# Find Lattice for 2-Torus with Given Riemannian Metric?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, robotics

I have a (standard?) 2-torus $T^2$ with a non-standard Riemannian metric on it

\begin{array}{lcr} g(\theta_1,\theta_2) & = & \begin{bmatrix}Izz1 + Izz2 + (L1^2*m1)/4 + L1^2*m2 + (L2^2*m2)/4 + L1*L2*m2*cos(\theta_2) & (m2*L2^2)/4 + (L1*m2*cos(\theta_2)*L2)/2 + Izz2\\
(m2*L2^2)/4 + (L1*m2*cos(\theta_2)*L2)/2 + Izz2 &                            (m2*L2^2)/4 + Izz2 \end{bmatrix} \\ \end{array}
(For definiteness, for this particular double-pendulum robot arm, the values of the parameters are  $m_i = 23.142$ kg, $Izz_i = 2.668$ $\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}^2$, and $L_i = 1.000$ m, but these values are mutable.)

It is my understanding that for any Riemannian 2-torus $(T^2,g)$ with a "flat metric" on it, there is a lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda$ with its inherited quotient metric being isometric to $(T^2,g)$.

My question is, what is the lattice inducing this metric and how would I determine that for myself?

[EDIT: As some possibly helpful and possibly irrelevant information, (I) (a) the length of the path $\gamma_1(t) = (t,0)$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ is Length1 = 49.947 $\text{kg}^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\text{m}$, (b) the length of the path $\gamma_2(t) = (0,t)$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ is Length2 = 18.268 $\text{kg}^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\text{m}$, (c) the length of the path $\gamma_3(t) = (t,t)$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ is Length3 = 48.980 $\text{kg}^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\text{m}$; (d) this leads to an "implied angle" of $\alpha = 76.394^{\circ}$ for The Law of Cosines, with $\text{Length3}^2 = \text{Length1}^2 + \text{Length2}^2 - 2\text{Length1}\text{Length2}\cos(\alpha)$. (II) (a) The path $\gamma_4(t) = (t,0.498t)$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ has Length4 = 41.220 $\text{kg}^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\text{m}$ and appears to minimize the length of all paths going once around $\theta_1$ and some positive multiple $b$ around $\theta_2$ at the same time; (b) this has an implied angle of $\beta = 51.769^{\circ} = \arctan\left(\frac{0.66}{1}\right)$. See [this Mathematica script](http://deadbeatjeff.sdf.org/Scripts/PathIntegralsRMetric04.nb).

EDIT 2: OK, so, [This link](http://deadbeatjeff.sdf.org/Scripts/curvature.m) I think I computes the sectional curvature correctly in MATLAB, and it is identically 0. Could someone help me find the lattice?

EDIT 3: [This link](http://deadbeatjeff.sdf.org/Scripts/Curvature01.nb) I think confirms the computation of the sectional curvature of my Riemannian manifold in Mathematica (although it heavily uses the fact we are in dimension 2; I'll need to work on that).

EDIT 4: I hazard the guess that the lattice in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with units for which being radians in each direction) with its standard Riemannian metric (with units for which being $\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}^2$) given by $\vec{v}_1 = \langle 49.947, 0\rangle \text{kg}^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\text{m}$ and $\vec{v}_2 = \langle 18.268\cos(\delta), 18.268\sin(\delta)\rangle \text{kg}^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\text{m}$, where $\delta = 180^{\circ} - 76.394^{\circ} = 103.606^{\circ}$ is the lattice I want (by properties of local isometries and covering maps); would anyone care to help me confirm or deny this? I'll post EDIT 4 as the answer if I don't get any feedback in a few days.]

Comment: Are you familiar with the covariant derivative, also called Levi-Civita connection on a Riemannian manifold?

Comment: Did you try to compute the curvature of this metric?

Comment: I have the Christoffel symbols computer in MATLAB. I shall either compute the Riemannian curvature in MATLAB or compute both the Christoffel symbols and Reimannian curvature in Mathematica (probably both). If the Riemannian curvature is zero, how would I compute the lattice (possibly for future reference)?

Comment: Solving this, unless there is something special about your parameters, amounts (mostly) to solving some nonlinear PDE, which one can do only numerically. The best you can hope for, then, is an approximate value of the conformal modulus of the torus.

Comment: (Now, I just need to figure out why that $\gamma_4(t) = (t, 0.66t)$ geodesic minimizes the path length among all paths that wind once or more around the longer "meridian" circle.)

Comment: An email from Tom Farrell (emeritus as Binghamton University) answered the question. I just want to mull it over and get all my ducks in a row, then I'll post an answer. Thanks for all the help.